# All file sizes in KBs (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

How do I get my File Explorer to display file sizes in MBs or GBs where necessary rather than always expressing them in KBs? Here's a picture:

[image: file sizes]

You'll notice that instead of saying `24 MB`, it says `23,826 KB`.

Comment: They assumed you'd never need more than 640KB, so just never expanded the structure to read it properly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explorer itself just can't do that.

But you can add the functionality through 3rd party extension software that adds customized columns to the views. This works in the same way that multimedia software can add extra columns with extra information (e.g. codec, duration, genre, rating) about media files.

Or you use an alternative file manager altogether. Almost all of them have far more customization and features than Explorer itself. As file-managers go Explorer is very basic. Just about any 3rd party file manager is more capable.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out! I've never actually noticed this until now, but my conversion skills are good so it wouldn't matter anyways.

This cannot be changed. You can however hover over it to view its size to the rounded unit, as shown below

[image]

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this either after literally using computers my whole life... I feel dumb now 